# How can i get my facebook social comments back

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-comments

I have recently migrated my website from HTTP to HTTPS. After the migration, all the facebook comments are disappeared. I found some solution in stock overflow for changing old http URL in og:url properties, but I couldn't get the comments after changing this property too, but after migration all the new https url comments are appear in my website,How can I get those comments back?is there any possibilities to edit http to https in my facebook comments moderate page?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1149655968420144

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to switch to https with the Plugin, you have to use the old URL. Try to use the old https URL for the "data-href" parameter:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://xxxxxxx" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

Comment: Hi luschn,
    Thanks for your quick reply, Its working for me, but I have only one query on this,I have updated only http post comments as per your suggestion, but the newest post are inserted with https,is it rise any problem on SEO perspective?

Comment: no, that should be no problem at all. it´s just that the comments plugin is bound to a specific url (including http/https), that´s all.

Comment: Hi luschn,Thanks for your reply